# Ok to use U.S. Visa gift card internationally?

Tags: united-kingdom, travel, gift-card

My daughter received a Visa gift card for Christmas that does not contain a chip.  She wants to use it when she travels to the U.K. in April.  Will it be accepted?

Comment: as far as  i know, in a great number of countries in europe ( atleast in mine , france  and belgium, where i've been) , swipe-only cards aren't widely accepted as payment form, and most payment devices have only chip/pin or approach (NFC) payment as options.

Answer (score 16):

Most cards do *not* work internationally - *"As of April 1, 2012, federal regulations prohibit gift cards from being used outside of the continental United States."*

See this link for more details: http://www.giftcards.com/gcgf/giftcards-work-internationally

Comment: In fact, I received such a card for Christmas, and there was a message to the effect of "Valid only in the United States" printed directly on the card. Reading the terms and conditions of the card should tell if it would be accepted internationally.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience they will not work internationally.